# Broken Pipe Error Redis

Tags: python, sockets, redis, redis-py

We are trying to SET pickled object of size 2.3GB into redis through redis-py package. Encountered the following error.

> BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
>
> redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 104 while writing to socket. Connection reset by peer.

I would like to understand the root cause. Is it due to input/output buffer limitation at server side or client side ? Is it due to any limitations on RESP protocol?  Is single value (bytes) of 2.3 Gb allowed to store into Redis ?

> import redis
>
> r = redis.StrictRedis(host='10.X.X.X', port=7000, db=0)
>
> pickled_object = pickle.dumps(obj_to_be_pickled)
>
> r.set('some_key', pickled_object)

**Client Side Error**

> BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/connection.py(544)send_packed_command()
>
> self._sock.sendall(item)

**Server Side Error**

> 31164:M 04 Apr 06:02:42.334 - Protocol error from client: id=95 addr=10.2.130.144:36120 fd=11 name= age=0 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=16384 qbuf-free=16384 obl=42 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=NULL
>
> 31164:M 04 Apr 06:07:09.591 - Protocol error from client: id=96 addr=10.2.130.144:36139 fd=11 name= age=9 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=40 qbuf-free=32728 obl=42 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=NULL

Redis Version : 3.2.8 / 64 bit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Redis' String data type can be at most 512MB.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is with the data size being passed to Redis. The command is sent to Redis as two items follows the RESP Standards

item #1

```
b'*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$8\r\nsome_key\r\n$2460086692\r\n'

Where
    *3           - indicates RESP array of three elements
    \r\n         - indicates the RESP Carriage return Line Feeder(separator)
    $3           - indicates Bulk string of length 3 bytes(here it is 'SET')
    $8           - indicates Bulk String of length 8 bytes(he it is 'some_key')
    $2460086692  - indicates Bulk String of length 2460086692 bytes (the length of value 2460 MB to be passed to Redis as next item )
```

item #2

```
b'\x80\x03csklearn.ensemble.forest\nRandomForestC...

Here item #2 indicates the actual data
```

- The moment item #1 instruction is passed to Redis Server, the server closed the connection as the value $2460086692 violated the protocol rule of 512 MB
- When the item #2 is sent to the Redis Server, we got Broken Pipe exception as the connection is already closed by the server.