# Redis and Django - Working with localhost redis, Broken pipe when using redis on another host

Tags: django, redis

I am running a local dev environment for Django and have separated out services like DB (MariaDB), RabbitMQ and Redis onto another host instance.

Everything is working as expected

Except for Redis, Django throws...:

```
python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 446, in send_packed_command
    raise ConnectionError(f"Error {errno} while writing to socket. {errmsg}.")
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 32 while writing to socket. Broken pipe.
ERROR:django.request: Internal Server Error: / (2023-11-09 07:29:04; log.py:224)
```

However if I configure Django to use a localhost redis-server instance it works ok.

The redis instance on the other host is accessible to the django server, i.e. I can connect to it using `redis-cli -h devservices.orb.local` from the django server (I'm using OrbStack to provide the server hosts, if that's relevant.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43204496/broken-pipe-error-redis.
Did you tried  django-redis?

Comment: Given the problem only happens when we switch hostname, that answer does not seem relevant.

Answer (score -1):

We need to see Redis configuration first, but I guess that will solve the issue: Please verify that the bind configuration in your Redis config file (redis.conf) is set correctly. By default, Redis is configured to only accept connections from `localhost`. You'll need to set it to `0.0.0.0` to accept connections from other hosts or set it to the specific IP of your Django server.

Comment: Note that redis-cli will connect to the remote (Clearly stated in the question). It is bound to `0.0.0.0`.